# How could I read a variable number of parameters?

Tags: c++, matrix, parameters, text-files

I´m reading a text file with numbers in order to store them in a matrix:

1 2 3 4 5

1 2 3 4 5

1 2 3 4 5

1 2 3 4 5

This code works for a 5x5 matrix, but if I wanted a 100x100 matrix, would I have to write `&matrix1[i][column]` 100 times?

Is there any way of doing this in a more dynamic form?

```cpp
FILE *file;

file = fopen("origin.txt", "r");
if (file == NULL){
    cout << "Error opening file" << endl;
}
int i = 0;
while (1){
    if (feof(file))
        break;
    fscanf(file, "%d %d %d %d %d\n", &matrix1[i][0], &matrix1[i][1], &matrix1[i][2], &matrix1[i][3], &matrix1[i][4]);
    i++;
}
```

EDIT(in response to @RemyLebeau): As I have never used fstream, I have been searching examples about its use and I have found this one:

```
std::ofstream output("inputMatrix.txt");
    for (int i = 0; i < numRows; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < numColumns; j++)
        {
            output << matrix1[i][j] << " ";
        }
        output << "\n";
    }
```

But I don´t know how to use ifstream. Could you give me a simple example of how to use ifstream?

Comment: Use `for (auto& row : matrix) { for (auto& e : row) { std::cin >> e; } }` ?

Comment: This can be done with `fscanf()` as well, just have it read one value at a time instead of multiple values. But since this is C++, you should be using C++ style I/O (`std::ifstream`, etc), not C style I/O.

Comment: @Jarod42 Could you detail where should I put that line? I don´t see how are you storing the values in the matrix

Comment: @RemyLebeau Outch, I hadn´t realised that! As I have never use fstream, I have found an example of `std::ofstream`, code what I´ll post in my question. Could you give me a simple example of `std:: ifstream`?

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to decide, what kind of matrix do you want to support in your code: only square matrices or more generic rectangular matrices.

Let's say you decided to support rectangular matrices. Then first two numbers in your file should specify number of rows and columns of the matrix, followed by actual data, e.g. 2x3 matrix may be described like this.

```
2 3
1 2 3
4 5 6
```

Second, you have to decide how you represent your matrix in memory. Let's assume, that you have class with at least the following members:

```
class Matrix2d
{
public:
    // create matrix of given size, filled with zeroes
    Matrix2d(int numRows, int numCols);

    // get reference to matrix element at given position
    // we assume matrix elements are of type int
    int& operator()(int row, int col);
}
```

Then reading the matrix will look like this (no error handling):

```
#include <fstream>

int main()
{
    std::ifstream is("origin.txt");

    int numRows, numCols;

    is >> numRows >> numCols;

    Matrix2d mat(numRows, numCols);

    for (int i = 0; i < numRows; ++i)
        for (int j = 0; j < numCols; ++j)
            is >> mat(i, j);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use like this:

```
ifstream file("origin.txt");
stringstream stream;

string str;
int i;
while (!file.eof()) {
    getline(file,str);
    stream.str(str);
    while (stream >> i) {
        cout << i << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
    stream.clear();
}
```